# python multiprocessing pool.map() wait until method is done

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm new to python multiprocessing and experimenting a little before the serious use. Right now I'm using pool.map() which seems to work great. But I would like to finish the pool jobs before continuing with the rest of my program:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

res1 = []

def my_func(x):
    print(mp.current_process())
    res1.append(x**x)

def main():
    print(mp.cpu_count())
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    tic = time.time()
    pool.map(my_func, [4444444,2222222,3333333,5555555,3333333,2222222,1111111,2222222])
    toc = time.time()
    t = toc-tic
    print(t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

print('Hi')
```

Right now the "hi" is printed in between my processes, but I would like to have the calculation processes finish first and at the end it should print "hi".

I tried out pool.close() and pool.join() but inside of my_func() it seems to change nothing and outside, say in main(), it does not know my pool object (of course since it is declared inside of main())

I know this is just a testing program, but I need this concept for a far larger project in my thesis. So i appreciate every help I can get. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

First, `x**x` with the values of `x` that you are passing is a *very* large number and will take a quite a while to calculate. On my desktop with 8 logical processors (`cpu_count()` returns 8), the `map` function took 99 seconds to complete -- but it does complete.

Second, the global variable `res1` to which each process is appending to is *unique to each process*. That is, each process is running in its own address space (this is a property of multiprocessing), and therefore has its own copy of `res1` and that is why the main process's `res1` will be empty upon return from the call to `map`. Instead, your *worker function*, i.e. `my_func`, should return its result and then the return value from `map` will be a list of all the return values.

Third, and this is a property of how processes are created under Windows, any statement at global scope that is not within the `if __name__ = "__main__":` block will be executed by every newly created process upon its initialization and that is why you see `Hi` printed `cpu_count()` times immediately. You should remove the call to `print('Hi')` at global scope and place it in `my_func` (see the last code example).

Because life is short, I have modified `my_func` just to return the square of its argument:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def my_func(x):
    print(mp.current_process())
    return x * x

def main():
    print(mp.cpu_count())
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    tic = time.time()
    results = pool.map(my_func, [4444444,2222222,3333333,5555555,3333333,2222222,1111111,2222222])
    print('Hi')
    toc = time.time()
    t = toc-tic
    print(t)
    print(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```
8
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=3232 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=3232 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=3232 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=3232 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=3232 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=3232 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=3232 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=3232 started daemon>
Hi
0.17300081253051758
[19753082469136, 4938270617284, 11111108888889, 30864191358025, 11111108888889, 4938270617284, 1234567654321, 4938270617284]
```

You will notice that although the pool size was 8, 7 of the results were processed by a single process in the pool. The reason for this is as follows. The 8 "tasks" to be processed, represented by the 8 numbers in the *iterable* passed to the `map` method are placed in an input queue of tasks to be processed in  "chunks" of a certain size. If you do not specify the *chunksize* argument, it defaults to `None` and the `map` method will compute a suitable value based on the size of the iterable and the pool size. In this case a *chunksize* value of 1 will be used. Idle processes will grab from the input queue the next chunk of tasks and execute the chunk. In this case one of the processes in the pool grabbed a chunk and executed it so quickly that it was able to go back and grab the next chunk and execute it before any other process in the pool was dispatched on another processor. In fact, it was able to do this 6 more times.

By making `my_func` fun a bit longer by putting in a call to `time.sleep` and ensuring that a *chunksize* value of 1 is used, we ensure that we give each processor a chance to grab a task:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def my_func(x):
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(mp.current_process())
    return x * x

def main():
    print(mp.cpu_count())
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    tic = time.time()
    results = pool.map(my_func, [4444444,2222222,3333333,5555555,3333333,2222222,1111111,2222222], chunksize=1)
    toc = time.time()
    t = toc-tic
    print(t)
    print(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

print('Hi')
```

Prints:

```
8
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=3116 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=3116 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=3116 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-2' parent=3116 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-6' parent=3116 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-7' parent=3116 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-5' parent=3116 started daemon>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-8' parent=3116 started daemon>
0.28499770164489746
[19753082469136, 4938270617284, 11111108888889, 30864191358025, 11111108888889, 4938270617284, 1234567654321, 4938270617284]
Hi
```

Simalry, by specifying *chunksize=8*, we are guaranteeing that all 8 tasks will be processed by one process while the other 7 sit idle:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def my_func(x):
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(mp.current_process())
    print('Hi')
    return x * x

def main():
    print(mp.cpu_count())
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    tic = time.time()
    results = pool.map(my_func, [4444444,2222222,3333333,5555555,3333333,2222222,1111111,2222222], chunksize=8)
    toc = time.time()
    t = toc-tic
    print(t)
    print(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```
8
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=22284 started daemon>
Hi
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=22284 started daemon>
Hi
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=22284 started daemon>
Hi
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=22284 started daemon>
Hi
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=22284 started daemon>
Hi
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=22284 started daemon>
Hi
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=22284 started daemon>
Hi
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=22284 started daemon>
Hi
0.9750022888183594
[19753082469136, 4938270617284, 11111108888889, 30864191358025, 11111108888889, 4938270617284, 1234567654321, 4938270617284]
```

Needless to say, this is a poor *chunksize* value to be used for this *iterable*/pool size combination.

Comment: First of all: Thank you so much for all this effort you put into this answer. It's a great help for me! However, I've got one question left, maybe this was not clear enough in my question: I would like to have the "hi" printed _after_ all 8 processes are finished. The "hi" actually only represents other code that should run after the method "main()" is done. So, I'd like to join all the computed stuff in one list and afterwards keep working with this list of computed values.

Comment: I have updated the first code example. All 8 processes are finished when the call to `pool.map` returns with the list of 8 results (`map` *blocks* until all elements of the passed *iterable* have been processed by the pool and results have been returned). So I simply moved the print statement following the call to `map`.

Comment: Ok, I get it. And say I have some more functions to execute after the pool and these functions make use of the variable "results". I can simply put all of this below the "hi" in the "main()" function, right? Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Don't worry. I just wanted to leave it open until it was really clear to me how it works.